# Fancytree. How to create folder?

Tags: jquery, fancytree

When I use html as a source, I can create folder by doing that:

```
<li class="folder">fff</li>
```

But how can I create folder programmatically using ext-edit extension? It creates documents by default.
I have the following code:

```
[...]
.on("nodeCommand", function(event, data){

    var refNode, moveMode,
    tree = $(this).fancytree("getTree"),
    node = tree.getActiveNode();

[...]

    switch( data.cmd ) {
        case "addSibling":
        node.editCreateNode("after", ""); // It creates document. I need folder.
        break;
```

Thus for creating a new node used editCreateNode method. But as I said, it creates document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editCreateNode()` accepts an init object, so you can do this:

```
switch( data.cmd ) {
    case "addSibling":
        node.editCreateNode("after", {
            title: "",
            folder: true
        });
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is better as far as no need to activate editing mode and expand parent tree.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `.addChildren()` method, passing in `true` for the `folder` property:

```
node.addChildren({
    title: "Programatically addded node",
    folder: true
});
```

An example can be found on the [Fancytree programming API example page](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-api.html) (click the "add single nodes button/source link).

Comment: This is the only section of help site I haven't visited. ) Thank you very much.